# Overriding variadic function in C++

Tags: c++, class

Recently I have encountered an interesting problem in an macOS IOKit driver I am working on - attempting to override a variadic function (with a format string and ...) in native macOS binary (the header could not be changed or else the hooking would fail), I cannot find a way to properly call the super implementation in my subclass. Is there something similar to va_list that I should pass after the format argument? Below is the specific related code.

```
IOReturn IntelBluetoothHostController::SendHCIRequestFormatted(BluetoothHCIRequestID inID, BluetoothHCICommandOpCode inOpCode, IOByteCount outResultsSize, void * outResultsPtr, const char * inFormat, ...)
{
    IOReturn err;

    err = super::SendHCIRequestFormatted(inID, inOpCode, outResultsSize, outResultsPtr, inFormat);
    if ( err )
        return err;

    return kIOReturnSuccess;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Ideally, fonctions taking c-ellipsis should also provide a version taking `va_list` (as `printf` and `vprintf`).

Comment: AFAIK it's impossible in general.

Comment: The painful thing is this function is wrote by Apple and it contains a bug… I am attempting to fix it by overriding it and inserting code after calling super. Maybe it’s not intended to be overridden, so it currently does not have a va_list version.

Comment: Could you have a variadic template overload instead?

Comment: Note that if the function is not marked `virtual`, then any calls to that function in Apple's class will keep using the buggy version defined in that class; they won't know anything about your new, overridden version in your derived class.  (And this has nothing to do with behing variadic.)